# Azure Elastic Job Agent - Credential Error

Tags: azure, t-sql, jobs, agent

I was used Logic Apps to refresh reporting tables. Now I am trying to use Elastic Agent Job to do that because of long-running time queries.

I understand the concept of target member and job etc. However, I have an issue with the **credentials**. In my case, I want to refresh my tables with the views that I created in the **same database** daily.

When shoul I use job_credential or refresh_cedential? I think in my case, I need to use refresh_credential but I'm not sure. I tried to test first, so I create a job 'CreateTableTest' that exist in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-jobs-tsql-create-manage?view=azuresql).

When I query `select * from sys.symmetric_keys` I see I have a credential that has a `key_guid :'xxx'`. So I created this:

```
create database scoped credential refresh_credential with identity ='refresh_credential', secret = 'xxx'
```

*Error: Failed to connect to the target database: Login failed for user 'refresh_credential'.*

How can I solve it?

Comment: Not sure how Elastic Agent is involved in this? Can you explain?

Comment: To use Elastic job Agent, I need to create Credentials first. That's where I stuck.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-jobs-tsql-create-manage?view=azuresql

Comment: Ok but this has nothing to do with #elasticsearch, I'm removing the tag